Multi- Column and Row Matching and Removal
I am trying to remove rows based on if the previous row was "added" and the current row is "removed". My goal is to identify the rows that are only "added".
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Event_Time': ['2024-05-28 12:37:00', '2024-05-28 12:41:00', '2024-05-28 16:12:00','2024-05-08 09:40:00'], 
                   'Name': ['Kenzie Doe', 'Kenzie Doe', 'Kenzie Doe', 'Abby Stone'],
                  'Action': ['Added', 'Removed', 'Added', 'Added']})

I converted the datetime so it can sort properly. The names are also sorted so all the actions for one user are together and by proper date time.
I am not sure if muli-row and column actions can be taken in python. I would like my final result to look like this:



Event_time
Name
Action




2024-05-28 16:12:00
Kenzie Doe
Added


2024-05-08 09:40:00
Abby Stone
Added




Why is the original first row removed? By your conditions, shouldn't only row 2 be removed?

The user was added and removed so they cancel out. The last add (for the user) was not removed so I am interested in it.

You can use a mask: ~(same & (rem | rem_add)):
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Event_Time': ['2024-05-28 12:37:00', '2024-05-28 12:41:00', '2024-05-28 16:12:00', '2024-05-08 09:40:00'],
                   'Name': ['Kenzie Doe', 'Kenzie Doe', 'Kenzie Doe', 'Abby Stone'],
                   'Action': ['Added', 'Removed', 'Added', 'Added']})


df['Event_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event_Time'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['Name', 'Event_Time'])

same = df['Name'] == df['Name'].shift(-1)
rem = (df['Action'] == 'Added') & (df['Action'].shift(-1) == 'Removed')
rem_add = (df['Action'] == 'Removed') & (df['Action'].shift(-1) == 'Added')


print(df[~(same & (rem | rem_add))])


Prints

           Event_Time        Name Action
3 2024-05-08 09:40:00  Abby Stone  Added
2 2024-05-28 16:12:00  Kenzie Doe  Added


Mask:

bitwise ~: inverse of the mask.

same: checks if the current row and the next row have the same name.

rem: checks if the current row has the action "Added" and the next row has the action "Removed".

rem_add: checks if the current row has the action "Removed" and the next row has the action "Added".

bitwise |: OR.

bitwise &: AND.



Worked perfect, god damn you are smart.

I would try this:
df.loc[
    (df["Action"] == "Added")
    & (df.groupby("Name")["Action"].shift(-1).ne("Removed"))
]

